# IP Canonicalization (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo

When I run [SEO Site Checkup](http://seositecheckup.com) on my site I get:

**IP Canonicalization Test: Your site's IP does not redirect to your site's domain name. This could cause duplicate content problems if a search engine indexes your site under both its IP and domain name.**

I'm running Apache, and the advice is to add the following to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Using [this test](https://www.site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html), I found that my site has 2 IP addresses, so I've added two rules in the Rewrite Engine section. But the website still fails the test.

Am I doing this right? Here's my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^104\.24\.122\.248
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^104\.24\.123\.248
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put those lines before WordPress dispatcher:

```
# BEGIN Redirect IP to domain name
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^104\.24\.122\.248 [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^104\.24\.123\.248
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.londoncitymedia.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END Redirect IP to domain name

# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache

# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: You're using Cloud Flare. The IP you're seeing is Cloud Flare's IP and not yours. Your real IP is 213.171.193.5 witch is not accessible. You then have nothing to do on your side.

Comment: Thanks Florian. Does that mean I can't do anything about the SEO score? I have access to CloudFlare. Is there something I can do in there?

Comment: You have nothing to do. You passed this test because your real IP is not accessible, but this tool lack the capacity to detect CDN like Cloud Flare. It's a problem with this tool and not a problem with your SEO ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot man really solved my issue :* I was really worried because my site's ip address was changed by cloud flare too and I was checking how to fix it. Thanks man.